# Reading fixed char arrays with right encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, struct, unsafe

I am trying to develop a modding tool for the games that were created by the Infinity Engine (Baldur's gate, planescape Torment etc.). I know what kind of data structures are in the Infinity Engine files an I am mapping some object from the byte[] contents. However it is lack of some performance and I'm not happy with this.

My mapped object on the managed world are structs and I know how much byte they are represented. Thus I decided to make the mapping process in unsafe code. I don't have any trouble with the Uint, ushort like value typed values however in string types I am having trouble about char[]  encoding problems.

as an example, you can see the struct gam file's Header in c#,

http://iesdp.gibberlings3.net/file_formats/ie_formats/gam_v2.0.htm

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 180,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct Header
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public fixed char Signature[4];

    [FieldOffset(0x0004)]
    public fixed char Version[4];

    [FieldOffset(0x0008)] public uint GameTime;

    [FieldOffset(0x000c)] public ushort SelectedFormation;

    [FieldOffset(0x000e)] public ushort FormationButton1;

    [FieldOffset(0x0010)] public ushort FormationButton2;

    [FieldOffset(0x0012)] public ushort FormationButton3;

    [FieldOffset(0x0014)] public ushort FormationButton4;

    [FieldOffset(0x0016)] public ushort FormationButton5;

    [FieldOffset(0x0018)] public uint PartyGold;

    [FieldOffset(0x001c)] public ushort NpcStructCountForPartyEx;

    [FieldOffset(0x001e)] public ushort WeatherBitfield;

    [FieldOffset(0x0020)] public uint NpcStructOffsetForParty;

    [FieldOffset(0x0024)] public uint NpcStructCountForPartyInc;

    [FieldOffset(0x0028)] public uint Unknown1;

    [FieldOffset(0x002c)] public uint Unknown2;

    [FieldOffset(0x0030)] public uint NpcStructOffsetForNonParty;

    [FieldOffset(0x0034)] public uint NpcStructCountForNonParty;

    [FieldOffset(0x0038)] public uint GlobalNamespaceVarOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x003c)] public uint GlobalNamespaceVarCount;

    [FieldOffset(0x0040)] public fixed char MainArea[8];

    [FieldOffset(0x0048)] public uint FamilarExtraOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x004c)] public uint JournalEntriesCount;

    [FieldOffset(0x0050)] public uint JournalEntriesOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x0054)] public uint PartyReputation;

    [FieldOffset(0x0058)] public fixed char CurrentArea [8];

    [FieldOffset(0x0060)] public uint GuiFlags;

    [FieldOffset(0x0064)] public uint LoadingProgress;

    [FieldOffset(0x0068)] public uint FamilarInfoOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x006c)] public uint StoredLocOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x0070)] public uint StoredLocCount;

    [FieldOffset(0x0074)] public uint GameTimeSec;

    [FieldOffset(0x0078)] public uint PocketPlaneOffset;

    [FieldOffset(0x007c)] public uint PocketPlaneCount;

    [FieldOffset(0x0080)] public fixed byte Unknown3 [52];
}
```

This is how map the this object ;

```
        string path = @"C:\Baldur.gam";

        byte[] content = IoHelper.ReadBinaryFile(path);

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pointContent = content)
            {
                Header* header = (Header*) pointContent; 
            }
        }
```

This is the result of char Signature I am having;

[0] = 21057 '剁'
[1] = 13624 '㔸'

These chars are really not reasonable. I guess this is caused by the encoding. Does anyone knows a solution for this? Or Do I have to read the char  arrays with Encoding.ASCII.GetString by myself? If I read a spesific sized byte[] with this method I get the true result.

And also there are different versions of these kind of structures. As an example in the sample above there is a V.2.0 version Baldur's Gate 2 Gam file. However in Baldur's Gate 1 the version changes into v.1.0 which doesn't works with my method. I would like to read these different methods and map them into a Model and then send them back to the UI Layer. Do you have any suggestion for reading the different kind of versions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem.

People i've asked said ;

*"In .net char is 2 bytes long. If you cast directly you cannot do it. To do this you can use Marshall class PtrToStructureMethod"*

I replace fixed byte members to string and use MarshalAs attribute like ;

```
    [FieldOffset(0x0004), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string Version;
```

And replace my mapping code to ;

```
        string path = @"G:\Games\BGOrg\BGII - SoA\save\000000001-Quick-Save\Baldur.gam";

        byte[] content = IoHelper.ReadBinaryFile(path);

        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(content.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(content, 0, unmanagedPointer, content.Length);

        Header header = (Header) Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanagedPointer, typeof (Header));
```

Works like a charm :)

Regards.